# Gather data into list, which has current user id inside Firestore/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm facing the issue with gathering data to the list _alldata as my implementing rule *.where(uid, isEqualTo: "ownerid")* is not working. I want to get only data which has ownerid inside and would be equal to current user.

Thank you in advance!

```
  getItemStreamSnapshots() async {
    final User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final uid = user.uid;
    final data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Books')
        .where(uid, isEqualTo: "ownerid")
        .get();
    setState(() {
      allResults = data.docs;
    });
    return "complete";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to put

```
.where("ownerId", isEqualTo: uid)
```

Right now you are querying for data where the property named (Whatever is in UID) is equal to `"ownerId"`.